# Function for the sequence $0,0,1,0,0,1,...$

Tags: sequences-and-series

I know the function $1+(-1)^n\over2$ generates the binary sequence, so I was curious about what would generate the "ternary sequence."

Comment: If you know complex numbers, try $\,(1 + \omega^n + \omega^{2n}) / 3\,$ for a suitable $\,\omega\,$.

Comment: @dxiv you should make that an answer

Comment: You can develop that into a full answer and I'll be happy to upvote it (self-answers are allowed, even encouraged, around here).

Comment: @dxiv considering I contributed nothing, I wouldn't feel right about it

Comment: Do you want $a_0=a_1=0$ and $a_2=1,$ or do you want $a_1=a_2=0$ and $a_3=1?$ Anyway, you are looking for a solution of the recurrence $a_n=a_{n-3}$ with given initial values. The solution is a linear combination of roots of the characteristic equation $x^3=1$ (cube roots of unity) with coefficients determined by the initial values.

Comment: @user189728 For another way, you could also use $\displaystyle\,\left\lfloor \frac{1+ (n \bmod 3)}{3} \right\rfloor\,$.

Comment: @dxiv I try to avoid use of discontinuous functions, but thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$ f(n)=\frac{1+2\cos(\frac{2n\pi}{3})}{3} $$